# Query state of all Midi knobs on midiInOpen

Tags: c, midi, multimedia, winmm

I have a MIDI controller with several knobs. Is it possible to query state of all values, which these knobs have, when I connect to the device using `midiInOpen` function without physically moving each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard MIDI message to inquire about the current state of a controller; messages are sent only when something changes.

Unless your controller has a vendor-specific extension that does exactly what you want, this is not possible.

Comment: Thank you for info. It was said to me, that it's common, that default value is used until it is matched with the value set from knob on the device.